# Click table row to select checkbox and disable/enable button jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

### HTML:

```
<table class="vi_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" class="v_checkbox"/>Select</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="pv">
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="v_checkbox"/></td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="pv">
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="v_checkbox"/></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="pv">
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="v_checkbox"/></td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<input id="percentage_submit_button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Set % for Selections">
```

### Css:

```
.diff_color {
    background: gray;
}

.vi_table {
    background: #c3ced6;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.vi_table thead tr th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

### Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.vi_table tbody tr', function (e) {
        var submit = $('#percentage_submit_button');
        var checked= $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');

        submit.prop('disabled', true);

        checked.prop('checked', !checked.is(':checked'));

        if($('.v_checkbox').is(':checked')) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass('diff_color');
            submit.removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('diff_color');
            submit.prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });


    $(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', !$(this).is(':checked'));
        $(this).parent('tr').toggleClass('selected'); // or anything else for highlighting purpose
    });

});
```

[So Far - Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sriganesh/hoqw2tay/6/)

I want to select the `checkbox` by clicking anywhere on the `row` including the checkbox. I would like to `enable` and `disable` the `button` if any one of the checkbox is selected in the `tbody`.

clicking the `Selectall checkbox` needs to select all the rows and enable the button.

Still I have some issues on selecting and deselecting the checkbox.

I gave the example of what I have tried so far, but I would like to make this clean like non repeating code. how can I make this code simple and more efficient way?

Thanks

Comment: hi i have checked your code. Fidle is not working because you have not included jquery Try this https://jsfiddle.net/hoqw2tay/1/

Comment: Thanks @manishshukla I updated it.

Comment: It's working. But still after I select the multiple rows and deselected it and still the row was highlighting. @manishshukla

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/hoqw2tay/9/

Comment: @manishshukla Thank you very much. Is it possible that we can add the select all code into the same function? selecting all should select all the tbody checkboxes and enable the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a few changes so the checkboxes align. See code comments for further info:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hoqw2tay/10/) in case Code Snippet doesn't work

```js
var testing = function (e) {
    var submit = $('#percentage_submit_button');
    var checkbox = $(this);
    if ($(this).is('tr')) {
        checkbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    }

    submit.prop('disabled', true); // Disable submit button

    checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.is(':checked')); // Change checked property
    
    if (checkbox.hasClass('all')) { // If this is "all"
        $('.v_checkbox:not(.all)').prop('checked', checkbox.is(':checked'));  // Set all other to same as "all" 
        if (checkbox.is(':checked')) { // change colour of "all" tr
            checkbox.closest('tr').addClass('diff_color');  
        } else {
            checkbox.closest('tr').removeClass('diff_color');  
        }
    }

    var blnAllChecked = true; // Flag all of them as checked
    $('.v_checkbox:not(.all)').each(function() { // Loop through all checkboxes that aren't "all"
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass('diff_color');
            submit.prop('disabled', false); // enable submit if one is checked
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('diff_color');
            blnAllChecked = false; // If one is not checked, flag all as not checked
        }
    });
    
    if (blnAllChecked) {
        $('.v_checkbox.all').closest('tr').addClass('diff_color');
        $('.v_checkbox.all').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('.v_checkbox.all').closest('tr').removeClass('diff_color');
        $('.v_checkbox.all').prop('checked', false);
    }
};

$(document).on('click', '.pv', testing);
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', testing);
```

```css
.diff_color {
    background: gray;
}
.vi_table {
    background: #c3ced6;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.vi_table thead tr th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="vi_table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="pv">
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" class="v_checkbox all" />Select</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="pv">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="v_checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="pv">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="v_checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="pv">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="v_checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input id="percentage_submit_button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Set % for Selections">
```

Comment: Thank you Jamie. Its looks clean. :-)

Comment: Hi, For some reason. After i implemented this code to my application, When I click the Checkbox on the tbody is not checked and select all is not working. do you know that i anything doing wrong?

Comment: @Sri have you added `all` to the class of the checkbox in `thead`?

Comment: Thanks @jamiebarker . Sorry I missed that part and after added it its all working.  The only one issue is when I click the row, the checkbox of the row is selected fine. But If I click the checkbox, `checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.is(':checked'));` this line is unselect it again.

Comment: @Sri Clicking the checkbox checks and unchecks at the same time?

Comment: @maiebarker Yes Jamie. When I debug it, after its hitting the line `checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.is(':checked'));` its unchecks it.

Comment: so basically, I could not select any of the checkboxes including the select all by clicking the checkbox exactly

Comment: sorry Jamie, I dont get that. Which part ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76451/discussion-between-jamie-barker-and-sri).

Comment: Hi @jamiebarker Still I could not come out from this issue Jamie. :-(

Comment: I'm in the chat room @Sri

Comment: sorry @jamiebarker. I just noticed

Answer (score 1):

I added an id to the select all input `<input type="checkbox" id="v_checkbox_all" class="v_checkbox" />Select</th>`

The select all input is checked first. Applying it's status to each input, then using the .each() to loop though each row and apply the row styles.

Demo here: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hoqw2tay/11/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var testing = function (e) {
        var submit = $('#percentage_submit_button');
        var checked = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
        var checkedAll = $('#v_checkbox_all');
        var isAllChecked = false;

        submit.prop('disabled', true);

        checked.prop('checked', !checked.is(':checked'));
        $(this).prop('checked', !$(this).is(':checked'));

        var checkedCount = $('.v_checkbox:checked').not('#v_checkbox_all').length;
        var totalCount = $('.v_checkbox').not('#v_checkbox_all').length;

        if (checked.prop('id') === 'v_checkbox_all') {
            isAllChecked = true;
        } else {
            if (checked.prop('id') === 'v_checkbox_all' || checkedCount === totalCount) {
                checkedAll.prop('checked', true);
            } else {
                checkedAll.prop('checked', false);
            }
        }

        if (isAllChecked) {
            if (checkedAll.is(':checked')) {
                $('.v_checkbox').each(function () {
                    $(this).prop('checked', true);
                });
            } else {
                $('.v_checkbox').each(function () {
                    $(this).prop('checked', false);
                });
            }
        }

        $('.v_checkbox').each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).closest('tr').addClass('diff_color');
                submit.removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('diff_color');
            }
        });
    };

    $(document).on('click', '.pv', testing);
    $(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', testing);

    $('#percentage_submit_button').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For selecting ALL checkboxes use this code:

```
 $('.v_checkbox').change(function(){
        $('.v_checkbox').each(function(){
        $(this).prop( "checked", true );
        })
    ;
    })
```